# R session gets stuck when writing a large array into a NetCDF file using ncdf4 package

Tags: r, netcdf

I'm reading a large NetCDF file (~2GB, 72 lon x 36 lat x 100 level x 2000 time cells) into RStudio, temporally filter it there and try to write the output into a new .nc file. However, RStudio gets stuck when writing the output file. I'm using RStudio version 1.1.456 and R version 3.5.1 on Mac OSX 10.12.5 (Sierra)

In the RStudio interface, I see the red "Stop" button and the command line without ">" as if the process were still running. However, when I use Terminal to look at the running processes using "top" command, I see that the "rsession" is stuck and only uses very little CPU-%. Shortly after starting the computation, the CPU-% is high and rsession is running, but soon thereafter, CPU-% drops and rsession becomes stuck. It shortly recovered a few times, but always gets stuck again, finally staying stuck. Furthermore, it sinks down to the bottom of the "top"-list as time progresses.
I tried the same code writing the output to a .RData file, which worked fine. So I assume there must be something wrong with my writing of the .nc output (see code below) or else R can't handle the large array to write to .nc format.
Is there an error in my code or is the data set just too big? Any help would be appreciated.

```
filtered.data.set <- array(NA, dim = c(72,36,100,2000))

# Try to write the output file as .RData file:
# save(filtered.data.set, file = "file_name.RData")
# This works fine.

# Now write the output file as .nc!: -----------

# Define the dimensions to use in the .nc file:
lon.vals <- seq(2.5, 357.5, 5)
lon.dim.nc  <- ncdim_def("Longitude", "Degrees_East", lon.vals)

lat.vals <- seq(-87.5, 87.5, 5)
lat.dim.nc  <- ncdim_def("Latitude", "Degrees_North", lat.vals)

level.vals <- c(1:100)
level.dim.nc <- ncdim_def("Level", "Integer", level.vals)

time.vals <- c(1:2000)
time.dim.nc <- ncdim_def("Time", "Years", time.vals)

my.nc.dims <- list(lon.dim.nc, lat.dim.nc, level.dim.nc, time.dim.nc)

# Define the variable to use in the .nc file:
current.var <- ncvar_def("Temperature", units = "[K]", my.nc.dims, missval = NA, 
longname = "Temperature", prec = "float")

# Create the new file:
current.data.set.nc <- nc_create("file_name.nc", vars = current.var)

# Write the values into the new file:
ncvar_put(nc = current.data.set.nc, varid = "Temperature", vals = filtered.data.set,
        start = c(1,1,1,1), count = c(-1,-1,-1,-1))

# close the variable in R to flush the values into the file:
nc_close(current.data.set.nc)
```

When terminating R, the result I get is a .nc file that is partly filled with the appropriate data. So the code seems to be working in principle, but might just be too slow. Is there anything I can do to speed up the process or alternatively keep the rsession from getting stuck? Again, thanks for any help.

Comment: what about the memory (%MEM)? you only talk about the %CPU. The code seems ok but hard to say like that!

Comment: Ultimately the code worked (albeit on a remote server). I did not check for memory-%, but will do so the next time I run the code. But thanks for the hint!